# Java - Exception evaluating

Tags: java, exception, evaluate

How can I evaluate an exception? I mean this:

```
try{

catch(Exception ex){

   if(ex == IOException){ //Error
       System.out.println("IOException caught: " + ex.toString());
   }

   else if(){

   }
   ....
}
```

I known there are other ways to achieve this. I just want to know if it's possible to compare an `Exception` "ex" to a defined `Exception` such as `IOException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice would be to add different `catch` statements for each `Exception` you need to catch, in inverted class hierarchy order (narrower to broader).

```
try {
    // TODO
}
catch(IOException ioe) {
}

catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Otherwise, you can always use `instanceof`.

```
catch(Exception ex) {
    if (ex instanceof IOException) {
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- The latter can be slightly more useful with Java 7 styled multiple-exception catch blocks, e.g. `catch (IOException | PatternSyntaxException ex)`.
- As [Codebender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2775450/codebender) mentions, you can match the exact class instead of using `instanceof` by employing the following idiom:

  `if (ex.getClass().equals(IOException.class))`.

  The `instanceof` keyword is more powerful than exact class comparison, but may perform slower.

  For instance, `new FileNotFoundException() instanceof IOException` returns `true`, because `FileNotFoundException` is a child class of `IOException`.

Comment: I know that adding more catch statements is the most common usage, but like I said in the question, I want to know how to do it with comparision. Thanks.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid hence the `instanceof` keyword.

Comment: Shouldn't you compare with `getClass()`. `instanceof` will give subclasses also and as I know is a little slower.

Comment: @Codebender it depends on what you're comparing. If you want the exact class rather than a hierachy comparison, `getClass` is suitable. I'll add it to my answer, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instanceof` operator. But keep in mind that you will check from the most specific to the most general.
Because a FileNotFoundException is also an IOException.

```
try{
    //do stuff
}catch(Exception ex){
    if(ex instanceof FileNotFoundException){ 
       System.out.println("FileNotFoundException caught: " + ex.toString());
    }else if(ex instanceof IOException){
        System.out.println("IOException caught: " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

But a cleaner solution will be

```
try{
    //do stuff
}catch(IOException ioe){
    //handle IOException
}catch(Exception e){
    //handle Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do more than one `catch` statements:

```
try
{
   //code
}catch(IOException e)
{
   //Code
}
catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    //Code
}
....
```

Also, you can do it like this:

```
try { 
  //Code
} catch( IOException | NoSuchFieldException ex ) { 
  //Code
}
```

If you want to use the same code with more than one `catch` exceptions.

I expect it will be helpful for you!